# Onmouseover on child change the parent  color

Tags: html, css, html-lists, onmouseover

`head` no background and color black ,on mouseover its color will be white and background black ,its working fine but

onmouse over on `content` i want to change the color of `head`?
how?
Is it possible only using css?

```
 <ul id="meg">
   <li><a href="#">head</a>
    <div>
    <h2>su head</h2>
    <p><a href="#">content</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">content</a></p>
     </div>
    </li>
 <li><a href="#">head</a>
    <div>
    <h2>su head</h2>
    <p><a href="#">content</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">content</a></p>
     </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use jquery for this not possible to handle parent on child hover event in css.

Comment: only option is jquery????  ooops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with JavaScript. Though I'm not entirely clear on what you wanted, I gave it a shot:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">  
function stuff(){
   var k = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
   for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
        var s = k[i];     
        s.firstChild.style.color = 'white';
        s.firstChild.style.backgroundColor= 'black';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="meg">
    <li>
       <a href="#">head</a>
       <div>
          <h2>su head</h2>
          <p><a href="#" onmouseover="stuff()">content</a></p>
       </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

this might work. i've knows css to be able to affect elemnts after the closing tag not before,so this is areverse of the "+" used to do that.

```
<style type="text/css">
   #content:hover - #head { background-color: black; color: white; }
  </style>

 <ul id="meg">
   <div id="head">
   <li><a href="#">head</a>
   </div>
   <div id="content">
    <h2>su head</h2>
    <p><a href="#">content</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">content</a></p>
     </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: +1 Thank you ,but i cant add another div,This is i used for multilevel menu,if i add another div its structure will change.

Comment: this is the only way to do it with css alone. otherwise you need javascript. jquery is not necessary.

Comment: hmm i guess it doesn't work then. looks he'll have to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried #meg li a:hover { background-color:#000;color:#FFF; }

Comment: on mouse over on child i want to change the color of parent